# Adding margin around a line segment

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a line segment given by its two endpoints - $(x1, y1)$ and $(x2, y2)$. For given margin $m$, I need to find the polygon around the line with margin.

When the line segment is a horizontal or vertical line I can easily determine the coordinates of the surrounding polygon (rectangle). For example:

[image]

But when the given line has a slope, I'm stuck here.

[image]

How should I calculate the coordinates in this case without using trigonometric functions and division (i.e. I know I could use line equation to determine the points)? I need that accuracy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need accuracy but you don't even want to use division? That may be a problem, the answer involves not just division but square roots as well.

Comment: There are many computer-stable algorithms for division ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Binary_division)). Can you explain what problems you have with division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to parametrize your line as follows:
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{matrix} \right) + t\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} x_2-x_1 \\ y_2-y_1 \end{matrix} \right) \quad t\in [0,1]
$$
If you take values of $t$ slightly smaller than $0$ or slightly larger than $1$, you get a slightly longer line. To describe the width use the normal vector
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}  y_1-y_2 \\ x_2-x_1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
So now the box is mathematically described by
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{matrix} \right) + t\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} x_2-x_1 \\ y_2-y_1 \end{matrix} \right)+s\cdot \left( \begin{matrix}  y_1-y_2 \\ x_2-x_1 \end{matrix} \right)  \quad t\in [-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon], s \in [-\varepsilon,  \varepsilon].
$$
If you want the offset to be $m$, you can choose
$$
\varepsilon = \frac{m}{d},
$$
where $d$ is the length of your line.